# Symfony2-Yaml:How to insert comment in yml file while dumping array

Tags: php, yaml, symfony-2.1

I am trying to create yml file using php symfony2 Yaml package.
I have an associative array like below:

```
$a = Array ( [name] => gfg  
             [time] => 1440 
             [vals] => Array ( ['# comment1'] => Array ( [temp] => Array ( [0] => sample [1] => rgr)  
                               ['# comment2'] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 ) ) ) ) )



$yaml = Yaml::dump($a, 10, 2);
  file_put_contents('../path/sample.yml', $yaml);
```

It is printing like

```
sample.yml

name: gfg
time: 1440
vals:
 -'# comment1':
    temp:
      -sample
      - rgr
 - '# comment2':
    quantity: 1
```

Expected:

```
sample.yml

name: gfg
time: 1440
vals:
 # comment1
 - temp:
      -sample
      - rgr
 # comment2
 - quantity: 1
```

can we do like this?Please suggest.

Comment: Did you find any solution?